# how do i post the path of a file into entry() in tkinter

Tags: python

i'm trying to make (text1) the Entry to get the file path that i open to show up
what i mean whin i open a file it show me the file path on the entry(textbox) 
ps: sorry for the bad example and English

''''python

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror
from tkinter import ttk
```

here is my class for the fream

```
class SchoolProjict(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, SetingPage):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
```

this on to test printing from entry

```
def printingstuff(var1):

    print (var1)
```

this to open a file i want it to chang the entry to show the file path

```
def load_file():
        fname = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Excel file", "*.xls"),
                                           ("HTML files", "*.html;*.htm"),
                                           ("All files", "*.*") ))
        if fname:
            try:
                print(fname)

                return

            except:                     # <- naked except is a bad idea
                showerror("Open Source File", "Failed to read file\n'%s'" % fname)
            return
```

here are the frames for the program

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        lablel = tk.Label(self, text = "Start Page")
        lablel.pack(pady = 10, padx = 10)
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Main Menu", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button1.pack()
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text = "Siting", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(SetingPage))
        button2.pack()

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        lablel = tk.Label(self, text = "Main Menu")
        lablel.pack(pady = 10, padx = 10)
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Start Page", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text = "Siting", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(SetingPage))
        button2.pack()

class SetingPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        lablel = tk.Label(self, text = "Siting Page")
        lablel.pack(pady = 10, padx = 10)
        text1 = ttk.Entry(self)
        text1.pack()
        text1.focus()
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Print from Entry", command = lambda: printingstuff(text1.get()))
        button1.pack()
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="open File", command= load_file, width=10)
        button2.pack()
        button3 = tk.Button(self, text = "Main Menu", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button3.pack()
        button4 = tk.Button(self, text = "Start Page", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button4.pack()
```

the main loop thing

```
app = SchoolProjict()
app.mainloop()
```

''''
i am sorry if it dose not make any sense

Comment: You can put a string into an `Entry` widget by calling its `insert()` method. Here's a little [documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/entry.html).

Comment: @martineau when  i used text1.insert(fname) on my function it say text1 not defined

Comment: i think i am doing it the wrong way

Comment: Actually the documentation link I gave you before was for a `tk.Entry`, not a `ttk.Entry` (which is [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Entry.html)). However I _don't_ think the differences between the two is causing the issue—it's because `text1` is a local variable in the `SetingPage.__init__()` initialization method, which means it can only be referenced from within it. See the @Bryan Oakley's answer to the question [Calling functions from a Tkinter Frame to an other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48731097/calling-functions-from-a-tkinter-frame-to-an-other).

Comment: @martineau thank you very much  i'll look into it now

Comment: Alaa Alharbi: You are welcome. Try to fix the problem(s) yourself, and if you still can't get it work for some reason, ask another question here.

Comment: [i posted this question again with some modified code and got the answer for it in the link ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56386715/how-to-entry-insert-work-with-frames-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class SetingPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ...
        self.text1 = tk.Entry(self)  #<== i want to show the path of the file i am going to open Here after i select it from openfile
        self.text1.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        self.text1.focus()
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text = "print text1", command = lambda: printingstuff(self.text1.get()))
        ...
```