# how to Entry.insert() work with frames in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-layout

i am trying to make a program that help me in my work at the school and i made lots of progress with it but i am messing now i need to fined how to make the path of the file to show on the Entry widget i tried lots of the stuffs in here and i may didn't git the idea behind it please help me with it

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror
from tkinter import ttk
import xlrd

class SchoolProjict(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.app_data = {"name": tk.StringVar(),
                         }
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage,  SetingPage):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

    def get_page(self, classname):
        for page in self.frames.values():
            if str(page.__class__.__name__) == classname:
                return page
        return None

def printingstuff(var1):
    print (var1)

def printontherthing(page_class):
    print(page_class)


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        lablel = ttk.Label(self, text = "Main Page")
        lablel.pack(pady = 10, padx = 10)
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text = "Siting", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(SetingPage))
        button2.pack()

class SetingPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        lablel = tk.Label(self, text = "Siting Page")
        lablel.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        text1 = tk.Entry(self)  #<== i want to show the path of the file i am going to open Here after i select it from openfile 
        text1.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        text1.focus()
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text = "print text1", command = lambda: printingstuff(text1.get()))
        button1.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="open file", command= self.load_file, width=10)
        button2.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
        button4 = tk.Button(self, text = "Main Page", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button4.grid(row = 4, column = 1)

    def load_file(self):
        fname = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Excel file", "*.xls"),
                                           ("HTML files", "*.html;*.htm"),
                                           ("All files", "*.*") ))
        if fname:
            try:
                # print(fname)
                value = str(fname)
                page_var = self.controller.get_page("SetingPage")
                page_var.text1.insert(0, value)
                return

            except:                    
                showerror("Open Source File", "Failed to read file\n'%s'" % fname)
            return

app = SchoolProjict()
app.mainloop()
```

it gave me an error whine i run it and select the file 
[this is what i have as an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSfeV.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your `text` an attribute of the class `SetingPage` by adding `self`.

```
class SetingPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ...
        self.text1 = tk.Entry(self)  #<== i want to show the path of the file i am going to open Here after i select it from openfile
        self.text1.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        self.text1.focus()
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text = "print text1", command = lambda: printingstuff(self.text1.get()))
        ...
```

Comment: If it helped, considering accepting the answer so the question can be closed.

Comment: i am sorry i am new to this stuff i did it now  and thank you very much